# How to Index Json Data using NEST Client for Elastic Search

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nest

How Can I index **json** data using **NEST**?

If I try to index some data in JSON, it gives me the following error :

```
MapperParsingException[Malformed content, must start with an object]
```

I saw we can do this using **PlainElastic.Net** etc.

Is there a way of doing it in NEST?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to index a single post in NEST:

```
var post = new Post() { Id = 12, ... }
var status = client.Index<Post>(post);
```

Here's how to bulk index many docs:

```
var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000))
    descriptor.Index<ElasticSearchProject>(op => op.Object(new ElasticSearchProject {Id = i}));

var result = this._client.Bulk(descriptor);
```

In the [NEST docs](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/core/), check out the Index and Bulk sections for more info.

Comment: This works awesome. Just for reference, I tried to both ways on my laptop, with ~67,000 records. Indexing each one individually in a loop took around 35 seconds. Using Bulk with batches of 10,000 took about 7 seconds.